# Performance Issue with Webpack

Tags: build, sass, webpack

I'm trying to switch sass building to Webpack in order to remove gulp (and maintain less tools).

The JS build in webpack is fast, and I have no problem about it.

My gulp scss build is really fast too, and take less than a second.

```
gulp.task('css', function(){
    return gulp.src('styles/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['> 0%'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

However, I try to reimplement the same in Webpack and I takes 10 secondes, the first build but also the watch process !

Here is the webpack code:

```
{
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'styles/main.scss'),
    // vendor: ['vendor'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'./public/css'),
    filename: 'main.css'
  },
  devtool: "inline-eval-cheap-source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['postcss-loader', 'resolve-url-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'resolve-url', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png|jpg|woff2|woff|jpeg|gif)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader' // old: 'file-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  postcss: [ autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['> 0%'], // ['last 2 versions'],
    cascade: false
  })
}];
```

Why does the process is 10x slower? What can I do to speed it up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The loaders will apply to all modules you imported inside your app, some of them might be *npm packages* from your `node_modules` folder.

Try to exclude these packages with the `exclude` property, like:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: ['postcss-loader', 'resolve-url-loader'],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'resolve-url', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png|jpg|woff2|woff|jpeg|gif)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'ignore-loader', // old: 'file-loader'
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `include` to only apply these loaders to files within your `styles` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing `sass-loader` and `resolve-url-loader` and using [fast-sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-sass-loader).

My re-build time went from 4-6sec to ~700ms.